# Run Watcher for jsbundling-rails gem in Rails 7 as systemd Service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, systemd, foreman, esbuild

I recently started playing around with Rails 7 alpha2 and tried to integrate the watchers for the new gems *cssbundling-rails* started by `yarn build:css --watch` and *jsbundling-rails* started by `yarn build --watch` into systemd services. I usually use systemd to control all relevant services (Puma, Postgres, Redis, ...) for my Rails apps, so it would be quite convinient to add these watchers to this setup as well.

With the service files given below, it works perfectly fine for *cssbundling-rails* but somehow the watcher for *jsbundling-rails* terminates immediately with exit code 0. It seems like esbuild does not enter watch mode. So, I assue it is an issue with esbuild.

CSS service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Rails CSS Watcher
PartOf=rails_app.service
After=rails_app.service rails_app_webserver.service
Requires=rails_app_webserver.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=rails_user
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/home/rails_user/rails_app/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/yarn --verbose build:css --watch

[Install]
WantedBy=rails_app.service
```

CSS service status:

```
rails_app_css_watcher.service - Rails CSS Watcher
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rails_app_css_watcher.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-10-29 09:53:37 CEST; 9s ago
Main PID: 17552 (node)
   Tasks: 23 (limit: 38018)
  Memory: 104.8M
  CGroup: /system.slice/rails_app_css_watcher.service
          ├─17552 node /usr/local/bin/yarn build:css --watch
          ├─17666 /bin/sh -c sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules --watch
          └─17668 /usr/bin/node /home/rails_user/rails_app/node_modules/.bin/sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no->

Okt 29 09:53:37 dev systemd[1]: Started Rails CSS Watcher.
Okt 29 09:53:37 dev yarn[17552]: yarn run v1.22.11
Okt 29 09:53:38 dev yarn[17552]: $ sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules --watch
Okt 29 09:53:38 dev yarn[17668]: Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
```

JS service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Rails JS Watcher
PartOf=rails_app.service
After=rails_app.service rails_app_webserver.service
Requires=rails_app_webserver.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=rails_user
Restart=on-failure
WorkingDirectory=/home/rails_user/rails_app/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/yarn --verbose build --watch

[Install]
WantedBy=rails_app.service
```

JS service status:

```
rails_app_css_watcher.service - Rails JS Watcher
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rails_app_css_watcher.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2021-10-29 10:16:17 CEST; 8s ago
 Process: 18729 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/yarn --verbose build --watch (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 18729 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Okt 29 10:16:17 dev yarn[18729]: verbose 0.147715144 Checking for configuration file "/home/rails_user/rails_app/.yarnrc".
Okt 29 10:16:17 dev yarn[18729]: verbose 0.147930862 Checking for configuration file "/home/rails_user/.yarnrc".
Okt 29 10:16:17 dev yarn[18729]: verbose 0.148159418 Checking for configuration file "/home/rails_user/.yarnrc".
Okt 29 10:16:17 dev yarn[18729]: verbose 0.148414149 Found configuration file "/home/rails_user/.yarnrc".
Okt 29 10:16:17 dev yarn[18729]: verbose 0.14857181 Checking for configuration file "/home/.yarnrc".
Okt 29 10:16:17 dev yarn[18729]: verbose 0.152530605 current time: 2021-10-29T08:16:17.072Z
Okt 29 10:16:17 dev yarn[18729]: $ esbuild app/javascript/*.* --bundle --outdir=app/assets/builds --watch
Okt 29 10:16:17 dev yarn[18729]: Done in 0.07s.
Okt 29 10:16:17 dev systemd[1]: rails_app_css_watcher.service: Succeeded.
```

Rails 7 introduces a [foreman runner](https://github.com/rails/cssbundling-rails/issues/1) for controlling Puma and the mentioned watchers. As foreman allows to export to systemd, I also tried this. The generated systemd file has the same problem but is given below for reference.

JS service file generated by foreman:

```
[Unit]
PartOf=rails_app.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
User=rails_user
WorkingDirectory=/home/rails_user/rails_app
Environment=PORT=5100
Environment=PS=js.1
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc 'exec -a "rails_app-js.1" yarn build --watch'
Restart=always
RestartSec=14s
StandardInput=null
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=%n
KillMode=mixed
TimeoutStopSec=5
```